# unable to change version in androidmanifest.xml

Tags: android

I am creating any android application and the want to upload in play store.My problem is the that when i try to change the version i am AndroidMainfest.xml and try to build the apk then version of application change to previous one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.menubar"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

 </manifest>
```

Answer (score 2):

in `Android Studio` just change `Version value` in `Build.gradle` this will override values with `manifest.xml`

```
 defaultConfig {
    applicationId "YourID"
     .......
    versionCode 001
    versionName '0.0.1'
}
```

If you are using `Eclipse` then just change version in `manifest.xml` and clean and built new apk. I am damn sure this'll change your app version.

```
  android:versionCode="1.1"
  android:versionName="1.0.1"
```

Comment: @vishalsanghani Then just change Version in manifest.xml and Built again a new apk. I am damn sure this'll change your Version.

Comment: I have tried the procedure you told but the version again set to 1.0 after building the app by exporting.

Comment: @vishalsanghani You need to increase Version Code.

Comment: I have also increased the Version Code as you mentioned.

Comment: @vishalsanghani NO.This is not possible.

Comment: You have to verify if your Manifestfile is readonly or not ? Check this could be the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Android Studio, you must change the App Version in gradle.

When you build your application, Gradle replace values from manifest.

If you are using eclipse, check if you do not change AndroidManifest.xml placed on build folder.

If this does not work, try to project > clean, make changes and rebuild.

Comment: Gradle what? Considering there're multiple build files in the structure, it might be worth clarifying the appropriate one.